# Android SDK: Cannot find Java, version of the file is not compatible

Tags: java, android, ant, sdk

I've installed Android *standalone* tools on Windows 7 32-bit, but when I am trying to run the android utility on the command line, the following error report is shown:

> No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the ADT, you need a version of JDK installed (...)

I have Java properly installed in *C:\Program Files\Java\JDK*, and my JAVA_HOME is set to this path. (**C:\Progra~1** - for ANT), PATH includes **C:\Program Files\Java\JDK** )
I have read on here in other posts that android utility simply starts find_java.exe, so when I start the program directly, I had this error:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows 
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether 
>   you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then 
>   contact the software publisher.

It just seems like the SDK manager installs wrong (64-bit? I am not an expert on that, but the error seems like that) of Java finder for some reason.

Has anyone encountered a similar kind of error? What could some reasons for that be?

Thank you in advance

Comment: preferably, JDK should be of the same version as the OS. ADT should be of the same version as the JDK. If 32-bit, then let them all be 32-bit.

Comment: I have 32-bit system, so JDK is 32-bit. The problem is that Android tools cannot find Java, otherwise the Java itself works, and Android tools worket, too, before I reinstalled them. I didn't change anything in the proccess, but just this error started coming out.